# Can one run for House and Senate at the same time?

Tags: united-states, senate, election-requirements

I am wondering about the idea of a senator running for the House of Represenatives because their senate seat is endangered. There are different reasons someone might want to do this. One could be unpopularity like Susan Collins. Another possible reason could be getting elected under unusual circumstances like Doug Jones. Could an endangered senator run in a safe district in the House of Representatives after dropping their Senate reelection?

If they could, they might have more of a chance because the party that is weaker in the state recognizes them.

Comment: "after dropping their Senate reelection" means they're *not* running for both at the same time.

Comment: "because their senate seat is endangered." Such a maneuver would kill voter confidence, regardless of which office they were voting about! You can't hedge votes by running for two offices.

Comment: The house is a step backwards. They'd rather go into lobbying if they lost their senate seat.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no restriction. The question was raised when Joe Lieberman ran simultaneously for Senate and Vice President in 2000 (had he won both, he would have resigned his senate seat and his replacement been picked by the governor). Given that state term limits on House/Senate seats were ruled unconstitutional in the 1990s, I would imagine that any attempt by states to limit candidates from running simultaneously for House and Senate would be also prohibited.

That said, it would be a challenging feat since the candidate would need to run two simultaneous campaigns in both a primary and general election. Lieberman was able to do this because he had such overwhelming support in his home state and didn't really need to do more than a pro forma campaign for the Senate.

Comment: To expand on this, the Supreme Court has rules that Constitutional restrictions on Congressmen are the **only** possible restrictions, so unless its in the Constitution it cannot be a rule.

Comment: @JonathanReez: But there are ballot restrictions on running for offices.  (Which will vary by state.)  For instance, in my state (last I checked), a candidate has to pay a filing fee, and either be the canditate of a recognized party (D, R, or various minor parties), or obtain a sufficient number of signatures on a petition to run as an independent.

Comment: @jamesqf correct, but these requirements are candidate-agnostic

Comment: Given that this has no references, and the other answer cites several relevant restrictions, this doesn't seem correct.

Comment: @JonathanReez: And how is "You may only file for one office" not candidate agnostic.

Comment: @jamesqf if "you may only file for one office" pertains to federal elections, its unconstitutional. If its about a state office (e.g. can't apply for Governor if you're in the Congress election), its a different manner.

Comment: @JonathanReez: Where has it been declared to be unconstitutional?  Another answer lists a number of states where there is a restriction.

Comment: @jamesqf probably not challenged in court yet, but could be reasonably expected to be unconstitutional

Comment: almost every state has at least some form of a sore loser law (you can't run in the general if you lose the primary) , but I don't think the SC has ever weighed in on it.

Comment: Also, as a VP candidate, Lieberman didn't have to do all that much, since it's generally the top of the ticket that people are really voting for/against.  This would not be the case in a simultaneous House/Senate run, since you're running by yourself in both cases, not just as a running mate on someone else's ticket..

Comment: @DarrelHoffman According to contemporaneous news coverage, Lieberman's campaign time was almost exclusively directed towards the presidential campaign. He was polling ridiculously far ahead of his republican challenger for the senate (around 80-20), so he would only dedicate the occasional day to his senate campaign.

Answer (score 31):

There are no restrictions at the federal level for running for multiple offices at once.  However, at least six states have imposed restrictions on running for multiple offices concurrently:

- Colorado ([Colo. Rev. Stat. § 1-4-501](https://codes.findlaw.com/co/title-1-elections/co-rev-st-sect-1-4-501.html))
- Florida ([Fla. Stat. Ann. § 99.012](http://www.leg.state.fl.us/Statutes/index.cfm?App_mode=Display_Statute&URL=0000-0099/0099/Sections/0099.012.html))
- Illinois ([Ill. Ann. Stat. § 10-7](https://www.ilga.gov/legislation/ilcs/fulltext.asp?DocName=001000050K10-7))
- Louisiana ([La. Rev. Stat. Ann. § 453](https://law.justia.com/codes/louisiana/2015/code-revisedstatutes/title-18/rs-18-453/))
- Oregon ([Or. Rev. Stat. § 249.013](https://www.oregonlegislature.gov/bills_laws/ors/ors249.html))
- Utah ([Utah Code Ann. § 20A-9-201](https://le.utah.gov/xcode/Title20A/Chapter9/20A-9-S201.html))

Comment: Precedent has generally been that states cannot put additional restrictions on candidates for federal office beyond what's stated in the constitution (which has meant that term limits on senators and representatives instituted by states have been overturned). I imagine that any restrictions at the state level against running for house and senate would probably also be ruled unconstitutional if challenged.

Answer (score 2):

@Don Hosek and @Joe C have good answers, but I would like to point out that there is precedent for this:

In 2016, Clair Van Steenwyk simultaneously ran for US Senate from Arizona and for the House seat from Arizona's 8th district, although he won neither primary.